# How can I update my entities in typeorm after changing them in my database?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

So I've added a relation to my SQLite database and now I want to update my entities in typeorm. Do I have to do this manually or is there a way with which I can generate those new entities. I used typeorm-model-generator for the initial generation of the entities...

I also tried using the generate migration command of typeorm but this turned out being used for updating the database according to the entities I would have written. (code-first)

Comment: Please add some code / example of what are you trying to achieve